# Only lets me make Stabilized Reflector Platform

Tags: fallout-4, xbox-one

I'm having trouble with the Molecular Level quest. I've started it and I have sided with the Brotherhood.

I decided not to start this quest as I got to it early and I've played probably about 2 and a half days worth of side quests since.

Now that I've come to actually want to start it, it's told me to speak to Proctor Ingram and she gave me a list of things I needed. I found the components for the Reflector Platform, but it only lets me make that, and nothing else!

I've scrapped everything at the airport including carpets and chairs, but I'm just so confused as when in workshop mode on the special things to make its just the stabilized reflector platform there?

I don't want to start from a later save as I'm so far ahead than I was when I first found this quest.

I would love it if someone could help me out.

Comment: any chance you can provide a screen shot of your construction window to see whats going on?

Comment: @lI how do I add a picture on here? I'm sorry im so clueless on here x

Comment: Just to make sure we're understanding you -- the problem you're having is that the only special component you see in the workshop is the stabilized reflector platform, correct? If so, that's normal -- you get instructions for that part first, and after it's built, you get the recipe for the other parts from your faction representative.

Comment: @pushasha yes but once ive made the Reflector Platform i cant make anything else.. No other items in the specials part comes up to make so I'm just verh confused as it means i cant advance in the story without making the portal?

Comment: So you've talked to Proctor Ingram after constructing the reflector platform? What does the quest log currently say? Also, look in your inventory -- the reflector platform parts list should be in there. Is the parts list for any of the other components in there too?

Comment: @pushasha the quest log says build the Reflector Platform..and ive done that :( Proctor Ingram gave me the list for that but thats it and she wont talk to me regarding the quest anymore.. Ive spoke to Elder Maxon but he doesnt have anything to talk about.. Ive went back to the railroad and spoke to Tinker Tom who has nothing to say about the quest.. Ive spoke to the leader of the Railroad, shes got nothing to say to me about it.. Im at a total loss of what to do :(

Comment: @RosieRussell I know this isn't a very elegant solution, but have you tried scrapping the reflector platform and building it again? Also, make sure you're building it in the correct location (the airport), and remove any carpeting below the reflector you build.

Comment: @pushasha it wont let me scrap the platform but it lets me store it in the workshop.. Ive made 4 haha and i set them all down just to see if anything would happen and stored them all, set down one and nope nothing. Yes its at the airport.. Im going to go talk to preston garvy and see if he has anything to say but this quest ive chosen is with the Brotherhood so cant think it will work..

Comment: @RosieRussell Did you see my note about the carpeting? Make sure any items in the immediate build area are scrapped so they don't interfere with the reflector placement. Seriously, it's a known bug that prevents the quest from updating.

Comment: @pushasha yep all carpeting is gone and anything that can be scrapped is scrapped.. I honestly think I'm the only person with this problem :( I'm so angry as ive played 4 days and 15 hours.. And the Molecular level quest i found when i was about 2 days in but decided to leave it as i knew it was a main quest so ive left it and found more locations and leveled up loads since then...

Comment: @pushasha i promise ive tried everything haha.. Im pretty clued up when it comes to fallout but im so confused as noone else has this problem on the internet? I cant make anything other than the stabilised reflector platform and when I set it down the game doesnt even notice that. Its madness :(

Comment: Are you on PC? We can fix it with console commands if it's that far gone.

Comment: @pushasha no im on xbox 1, ive just saved and killed Ingram and the Brotherhood killed me and im not allied with them but it let me loot her body before and she had signal intercepture plans on her? I tried running to the workbench to see if i could make anything else but they killed me before haha.. I wanted to side with the brotherhood though but if this is the only way I can progress and actually complete the main quest I guess I'll have to do it?

Comment: @pushasha.. I may have just killed everyone at Boston Airport.. Now my quest has changed and it says I can talk to the Railroad or the Minutemen.. I saved before I killed Ingram so I'll see if this works and I can carry on with the quest via a different faction haha... Oh im so annoyed, i wanted to go with the Brotherhood

Comment: It doesn't look like anyone had directed you to the Fallout wiki yet: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Molecular_Level. This is a repository of information, as opposed to this site for specific questions and answers. There are lists of known bugs as well as detailed walkthroughs. Should be helpful.